# Excel VBA Sum up/Add values together, even those with commas/decimal

Tags: excel, vba, sum, decimal, cell

I have a problem where I can't add numbers with decimals. Only numbers with no decimals.

I have written a code to sum up values from different cells. This work fine as long as the numbers are without decimals.

Here is my code:

```
Sub SumValues()

'This makro is made to add values together depending on 
'x amount of Sheets in the workbook:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'A will sum up the values from each cell, 
'depending on the amount of Sheets  in the this Workbook:
A = 0

For I = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    'Adding the values from cell E5 to Cells(5, 5 + (I - 1) * 3), 
    'with the distance 3 between each cell:
    A = A + Cells(5, 5 + (I - 1) * 3)
Next I

'The values A that is added togheter from the cells, is now put in a cell:
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=" & A & ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So for 3 number of sheets, "I" goes from 1 to 3.
So if my cells contain these numbers:

`Cell(5,5) = 2`

`Cell(5,8) = 3`

`Cell(5,11) = 8`

I get the sum in `Cell(1,1) = 13`

But if I have these values:

`Cell(5,5) = 2,2`

`Cell(5,8) = 3`

`Cell(5,11) = 8`

I get the "run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" Error message when running script.
Any suggestions?

Another question is if it is possible to get the formula into the cell I am adding up the values?
For Examlpe if I have 3 Sheets in my Workbook, it will sum up the values from `Cell(5,5)` , `Cell(5,8)` and `Cell(5,11)`. 
The sum is shown in `Cell(1,1)`.
But all I get is the number, not the formula.
Is it possible to make the Cell show the formula "`=E5+H5+K5`"?
This last question might be a "fix" for the first question, if it is the separator "," that is making trouble, maybe?

Thanks

GingerBoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tested and working fine

1. Declare your variables
2. You need to qualify your objects with a worksheet
3. No need to toggle off `Screen Updating` here. You are just modifying one cell

This code will place the `Value` in `A1` and the `Formula` in `B1`

---

### Disclaimer:

Your code, and the code below, is subject to a potential `Type Mismatch Error` if you feed any cell with a non-numerical value into your loop. If there is some chance of any non-numerical cell being in the sum range, you can avoid the error by nesting something like the following inside your loop: `If ISNUMERIC(Range) Then`.

---

```
Sub SumValues()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim A As Double, i As Long, Loc As String

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    A = A + ws.Cells(5, (5 + (i - 1) * 3))
    Loc = ws.Cells(5, (5 + (i - 1) * 3)).Address(False, False) & "+" & Loc
Next i

ws.Range("A1") = A
ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=" & Mid(Loc, 1, Len(Loc) - 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfect!
I Haven't "decleared" vaules before. This is often necessary?

Comment: This is always necessary if you want reliable code. Look up glorious line of code that is `Option Explicit` and add it to every code you write. It will force you to declare variables until it becomes habit

Comment: Misread your question, you declare variables, not values. The variable you want here happens to store values. Other variables store strings, or object properties, or arrays, etc.

Comment: Still kinda new to VBA, and see that there is alot to learn :-)
Thanks for the help! 
Have a great day!